# How to access array value of count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I access the value of the array of COUNT(*)? I get the error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array when i tried to use `$availableRooms[3]['COUNT(*)']`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => king
            [COUNT(*)] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => family
            [COUNT(*)] => 7
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => quad
            [COUNT(*)] => 8
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => standard
            [COUNT(*)] => 7
        )

)
```

I need to get the value of count. In this case when i use `$availableRooms[3]['COUNT(*)']` it should output `7`

```
**EDIT**
```

**Query**

```
$availableRooms = DB::select("SELECT
      category, COUNT(*)
      FROM available_rooms
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          -- room is booked on the requested dates (...not)
          SELECT 1
          FROM room_reserveds
          JOIN bookings ON room_reserveds.bookingID = bookings.bookingID
          WHERE room_reserveds.roomID = available_rooms.roomID
          AND $checkOutDate > checkIndate
          AND $checkInDate < checkOutDate
      )
      GROUP BY category");
```

Comment: You can use alias on your query like `COUNT(*) as count`

Comment: Objects and array use different notation to access values: `->` for objects `[]` for arrays

Comment: show  your database query

Comment: @SaurabhMistry see eidit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array contains objects, so you can't use the array notation to get these properties. And because it's a special key, you can get the property by placing the name between `{}` as a string.

```
$availableRooms[3]->{'COUNT(*)'};
```

I suppose this results comes from a database query. A better solution would be to give this result an alias that can be referenced directly.

```
// SQL: 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ...

// PHP:
$availableRooms[3]->count;
```